# Using zend framework in joomla

Tags: zend-framework, joomla, joomla1.5

Is that possible? How do i do it? I have tried installing in the plugin manager but still it's not reflected in the plugin screen. Any hints or guide would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: My bad, I voted up for the answer but forgotten to select the tick to accept the answer! Noob me.

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework works as a library as well as an MVC Framework.

What you can do is copy the Zend Framework library into your project. Then you can basically include the relevant classes you would like to use.

This is an example for using the Zend_Json::encode() function:

```
$zend_library_path = 'ZendFramework/library/Zend';
set_include_path ( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $zend_library_path);
include_once('Json.php');

echo Zend_Json::encode( array('hello'=>'world') );
```